# Whats the difference of Podfile post_install config loops in build_configurations

Tags: ios, xcode, mobile-development, podfile, post-install

I've seen many different answers some with this loop config:

```
post_install do |installer|
 
  installer.pods_project.build_configurations.each do |config|
     config.build_settings['CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED'] = "NO"
     ...
```

others with:

```
installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED'] = "NO"
      ...
```

They seem to have the same result apparently... but one goes through each `target` in `targets` then cycles through each `config` in `build_configurations` of that `target`... whereas the other just goes through each `config` in `build_configurations` at same level as `targets` (level of `pods_project`)

are these the same thing? can some one please clarify whats is happening here?

if possible, also provide a link to where can I learn more about these Podfile post_install configuration options and all its possibilities

Comment: actually there seems to be a difference but I still haven't figured it out yet